Next JS Lazy loading script file
I have next JS application with multiple pages I want to load a script on page and that is calling two more scripts internally, I have tried using below approach
        import Script from 'next/script';


         <Script
            strategy="lazyOnload/beforeInteractive/afterInteractive"
            src="path/to/script"
            id="unique-1"
        />

Using above code I am able to load the script on my page but the script which is called internally are not getting loaded on this page
Can I get some inputs on this Thanks in advance


What do you mean by "called internally" ? 2. See Next.js <Script>

